# Code only updates false value in DB, but not true

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a strange case when only false state is saved in to the database. When the "state" should be true, my query still executes false.

I have controller with this function

```
public function change_active_state_post()
{
    $id['id_location'] = $this->input->post('id_location');
    $state['active'] = $this->input->post('state');
    var_dump($state['active']);
    $this->locations->update($state, $id);
}
```

This is MY_Model update function

```
function update($data,$conditions,$tablename=""){
    if($tablename=="")
        $tablename = $this->table;
    $this->db->where($conditions);
    $this->db->update($tablename,$data);
    var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

When i make a request to deactivate location i get following data in my log & database is properly updated

```
Location.php:196:string 'false' (length=5)
MY_model.php:46:string 'UPDATE `Locations` SET `active` = 'false'
WHERE `id_location` = '2'' (length=67)
```

But when i make request to activate location i get following data in my log & and database value isn't updated

```
Location.php:196:string 'true' (length=4)
MY_model.php:46:string 'UPDATE `Locations` SET `active` = 'true'
WHERE `id_location` = '2'' (length=66)
```

The problem is that active column never get's updated with value 1 or true. It's stays 0, but if i wan't to make it 0 from 1 it will always work.

active column type in database is `tinyint(1)`

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide: Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

This additional check helped me to insert data properly

```
if($this->input->post('state') == 'true'){
   $state['active'] = true;
}else{
   $state['active'] = false;
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of active field in your db? what happen when you run false query in mysql console?

Comment: make sure your database name is set `$tablename = $this->table;`

Comment: The additional check can be shortened to `$state['active'] = ($this->input->post('state') == 'true');`

Comment: Woow. Nice! thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `'true'` is quoted so it is being inserted as a string:

```
MY_model.php:46:string 'UPDATE `Locations` SET `active` = 'true'
```

In MySQL both strings `'true'` and `'false'` are converted to `0` when placed into `tinyint(1)` column, since neither is proper numeric value.

Using values `0` and `1` will work. MySQL also defines constants `FALSE` (`0`) and `TRUE` (`1`), so those will also work as long as you insert them unquoted and not as strings.

Comment: I'm using mysql. Ok will run some test, to convert string to "true, false", but as far i know this should be done automatically

Comment: Yep! I have updated the question with my solution. I had to make some additional checks in order to insert the as "true,false". Thx for the help!